# java exit while press ajbutton

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

I have a jbutton and when I press it I want that my frame close.

This is my code but it doesn't work

```
Frame frame=new Frame();
int n = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(frame,"Are you sure to exit","Really?",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
if(n == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
```

Comment: `this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE)` doesn't cause frame *to* close, but describes what strategy should be used *when* frame will be closed.

Comment: [JFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setDefaultCloseOperation(int)) is quite explicite : _Sets the operation that will happen by default when the user initiates a "close" on this frame_